# Use hierarchical Query to get days between two dates

Tags: oracle

I want to generate Days between two given Dates, So I have found the following way to do that using hierarchical Query:

```
select CONTACT_ID, S_DATE, E_DATE, trunc(S_DATE)+level-1 dt
       from CONTACTS
        connect by trunc(S_DATE)+level-1<=trunc(E_DATE) 
        and prior dbms_random.value is not null and prior CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID = CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID;
```

so, if I have the following row:

`1, 2016-01-01 23:00:00, 2016-01-02 05:00:00`

the above query will generate the following output:

`1, 2016-01-01 23:00:00, 2016-01-02 05:00:00, 2016-01-01 00:00:00`

`1, 2016-01-01 23:00:00, 2016-01-02 05:00:00, 2016-01-02 00:00:00`

but I don't understand how the query works, especially this part : `and prior dbms_random.value is not null and prior CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID = CONTACTS.CONTACT_ID`

can anyone explain it to me please ?

Comment: [This Oracle community link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2526535?start=0&tstart=0) explains it quite well, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [recursive subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG) to get the very same result, which is in my opinion much more intuitive.

```
with data(CONTACT_ID, S_DATE, E_DATE, DT) as (
    select CONTACT_ID, S_DATE, E_DATE, S_DATE  from CONTACTS
    union all
    select CONTACT_ID, S_DATE, E_DATE, DT+1 from data where DT+1  <= E_DATE
)
select CONTACT_ID, S_DATE, E_DATE, DT
from data
```

The first select in the subquery defines the initial condition, i.e. you start with `S_DATE` (in the 4th column).

The second select (which is repeatedly performed) defines the step `DT + 1` and the WHERE clause defines the termination condition.

The recursive subquery factoring is AFAIK standard and was introduced in [11.2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/wnsql.htm#SQLRF50926)